# SAS- setting missings to a range of columns based on the value of another variable

Tags: arrays, sas, missing-data

I currently have a dataset that includes an ID for each person, and then variables called day1 through day1826 that are binary indicators of availability of a drug on each of those days. I need to censor individuals on certain days. For example, if a person needs to be censored on day500, then I need day500 to be set to missing, as well as every day variable after that (i.e. day500 through day1826). I have a variable called time_for_censor that indicates what day to start the missings.

How can I code this in SAS?

I've tried to code it in a loop like this:

```
array daydummy (1826) day1-day1826; 
if time_for_censor ne . then do time_for_censor=1 to 1825; 
  daydummy(time_for_censor)=.; 
  daydummy(time_for_censor + 1) =.; 
end;
```

Comment: What did you try?  How did it not do what you wanted?

Comment: I've tried to code it in a loop like this:
array daydummy (1826) day1-day1826;
if time_for_censor ne . then do time_for_censor=1 to 1825;
daydummy(time_for_censor)=.;
daydummy(time_for_censor + 1) =.; end;

I definitely realize this isn't the right approach, but I've never used a value from another variable as part of a do loop so I got very lost with how to do this :)

Comment: Moved code from your comment into the question.  So TIME_FOR_CENSOR has a number between 1 an 1,826 when there is censoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop from the censor date to the end of the array.

```
array daydummy (1826) day1-day1826; 
if not missing(time_for_censor) then do index=time_for_censor to 1826; 
  daydummy(index)=.; 
end; 
drop index;
```

You might need to change the lower bound on the do loop to time_for_censor+1 depending on the whether the values are valid on the censoring date or not.